# Is there a way for bigint datatype to accommodate more than 19 digits in informatica?

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-cloud

> I have a informatica mapping as follows
>
> 1. The source is oracle database and at the source qualifier I'm doing simple sum of all columns using SQL; out of which one column has bigint datatype.
>
>    At the target is greenplum database that should store the outcome of sum.

The row where it exceeds 19 digit sum is ignored by informatica and entered in rejected rows. Is there a way to avoid this problem other than changing the datatype of bigint at source qualifier or at target?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Transformation Data Types](https://docs.informatica.com/integration-cloud/cloud-data-integration/current-version/function-reference/datatype-reference/transformation-datatypes.html). Bigint allows precision of up to 19 digits. For larger ones I guess you need to use Decimal. Have you tried that?